# The sound isn't played

Tags: coronasdk

I work with Corona SDK trial version on Win32 platform.
The program works ok , except the sound playing:

```
media.playEventSound( "beep.caf" )
```

I have the beep.caf file in the folder. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this problem when I was first starting out with Corona also. The problem is that windows doesn't play .caf files (which is a mac format).

I recommend grabbing the file ...\Corona SDK\Sample Code\Hardware\Accelerometer1\beep_wav.wav and copying it to your project. Then you just need to replace beep.caf with beep_wav.wav. beep_wav.wav and beep.caf are the same sound anyway!